# Is colormapping possible in holoviews?

Tags: bokeh, holoviews

I want to conduct [colormap normalization](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html) using holoviews, more specifically holoviews using bokeh backend. Apparently colormapping is supported by [bokeh](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/color_data_map.py) but I couldn't figure out how to properly pass the arguments to the bokeh backend.

Does anybody know if this is feasible?

Comment: HoloViews+Bokeh will normalize your colormap by default, so I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: the question is whether it's possible to customize this mapping, i.e give more/less weight to certain regions (or do log-transform etc.).

Comment: one solution would be to transform the data itself, but isn't this the sole reason why matplotlib  for example includes the norm parameter that allows to control that?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily switch between linear and log colormapping in HoloViews using the `logz` option, as in `hv.Image(...).options(logz=True)`:

[image]

Not sure of the best way to do arbitrary weighting, but you can always make a custom colormap for Bokeh by concatenating any lists of colors you like.